# Hide a parent element based on specific html tag contents

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do something similar to [How to hide an element, based on its text, with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786422/how-to-hide-an-element-based-on-its-text-with-javascript) and [Hiding a parent element using JS/JQuery based on the alt tag of a child element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25537630/hiding-a-parent-element-using-js-jquery-based-on-the-alt-tag-of-a-child-element)
but it's a bit more complicated than that. Here's the entire element (a list item containing lots of stuff) I want to hide:

```
<li>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="fulllink" data-href="hideme/some/url" data-title="hideme - some more text">
            <a href="/some/url" rel="stuff">
        </div>
        <div id="fullimage" class="theimage">
            <img src="/some/url" title="hideme - some more text" alt="thisis/hideme text">
        </div>
        <div class="captionwrapper">
            <div class="caption">
                <p>
                    <a class="" title="" href="hideme/some/url">more text</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

I want to hide this `li` element based on the specific content "**hideme**", which appears several times, but as you can see never on its own. It should be hidden as the page loads, so no user action required.

I've tried to come up with a solution based on similar questions on stackoverflow, but so far unsuccessfully.

Comment: Post your jQuery code.

Comment: Put your whole code in jsfiddle and show us.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand the question. Are you looking for something like that? http://jsfiddle.net/kjrw0jna/

Comment: @Tobías: Yes, that seems to work!

Comment: Ok, then I post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function to get the `html` contents of each `li` and then search if it contains the desired text: "hideme".

```
$("li").each(function () {
    if ($(this).html().indexOf('hideme') > -1) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kjrw0jna/)